# Python - Problema al establecer hora a formato 24h

Tags: python

Estoy creando una app en la cual debo transformar la hora a formato 24h, por ejemplo de 5:33 a 17:33.

Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
time = "5:33 PM"
hour = datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M %p').time()
```

Al efectuar dicha acción el formato no cambia, es decir de "5:33 PM" obtengo "05:33:00", en lugar de 17:33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formatos de hora:

- `%H` es para hora en formato 24h, notar que este formato ignora lo que capture `%p`.
- `%I` es para hora en formato 12h, se usa junto a `%p` para leer/decir si es AM o PM.

Es decir que al hacer `datetime.strptime('5:33 PM', '%H:%M %p')` estás interpretando el `5` como hora en formato 24h, para que te lo lea como hora en 12h debes usar este formato: `'%I:%M %p'`

Comment: Gracias. ¿%H no debe ser usado junto a %p?, sucede que recibo la hora de la siguiente forma "5:33 PM" y posteriormente dicha hora formatearla a "17:33", sin embargo realizando "%H:%M", no obtengo el cambio. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Si lo puedes usar, pero el formato `%H` ignora lo que capture `%p`, por eso, para obtener el comportamiento que deseas debes usar `%I` en vez de `%H`